# Highstock panning asynchronously loading data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Using Highstock is it possible to drag the chart and load the data asynchronously?

I've seen the async demo on the highcharts website http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/5zPLV/

However this uses the navigator/scrollbar to move the chart along the series and loads the data when you stop sliding it along, Ideally I want to use the panning capability of highstock to move along  instead of the navigator as it takes up too much space.

Playing around with the demo if I turn off the navigator and scrollbar and disable the zoomtype: x then as soon as you start dragging the chart it tries to fetch the data, making the chart unusable.  Here is a fiddle of that http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/6YSvk/

```
navigator: {enabled: false}, scrollbar: {enabled: false}
```

Ideally we'd need to know when the user starts dragging and when they stop then load the data.

Is this even possible to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is possible, but it won't be easy.

As you wrote, you should start with detecting drag & drop. It's not possible using build-in options, but we can add our own event listeners. Take a look at this code:

```
new Highcharts.StockChart({
    // here comes your chart options, but we can pass callback function as the second parameter
}, function (chart) {
    var report = document.getElementById('report'), // just an element to display current extremes
        xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        startX;

    function drag(e) {
        e = chart.tracker.normalizeMouseEvent(e);
        startX = e.chartX;
    }

    function drop(e) {
        e = chart.tracker.normalizeMouseEvent(e);

        var delta = e.chartX - startX,
            extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
            newMin = Math.round(extremes.min - delta),
            newMax = Math.round(extremes.max - delta);

        // display extremes retrieved by panning
        report.innerHTML = "<b>From:</b> " + new Date(newMin) + " <b>to:</b> " + new Date(newMax);
    }

    // bind events
    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', drag);
    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseup', drop);
});
```

Simply we detect mouseDown & mouseUp events, then calculate the difference, translate difference to x data and finally, substract difference from extremes.

Here you can find the jsfiddle demo with code posted above: http://jsfiddle.net/dSEAA/1/

Comment: chart.tracker no longer works with Highcharts :( Is there another way to normalize the event?

Comment: you can use `chart.pointer.normalize(e)` instead in Highcharts 9.0

Comment: @slawekkolodziej `delta` will be the difference in pixel coordinates from the starting point. What's missing in your example is the translation to x values (milliseconds)

Comment: @mediafreakch you dug a post from more than 8 years ago! :-) I believe that `e.chartX` was x coordinate in x-axis values, not a pixel position. I believe that today Highcharts offers a better way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

To make @slawekkolodziej's example work, you need to translate the delta into ms on the xAxis, then update the xAxis extremes like so:

```js
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    // chart options go here
}, function(chart) {
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        startX;

    function drag(e) {
      e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
      startX = e.chartX;
    }

    function drop(e) {
      e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);

      var delta = e.chartX - startX,
        extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
        deltaMs = (extremes.max - extremes.min) / chart.plotWidth * delta,
        newMin = Math.round(extremes.min - deltaMs),
        newMax = Math.round(extremes.max - deltaMs);

      xAxis.setExtremes(newMin, newMax)
    }

    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', drag);
    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseup', drop);
  });
});
```

Here's a working example with async data loading: http://jsfiddle.net/xw7goLj4/5/